# Join strings in sql update query

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I have two fields with a string in it, and I want a combination of those in a third field like:

```
UPDATE table SET field3=field1 . '_' . field2
```

What would be the right syntax for that?

It is MySQL.

Okay that CONCAT Thing worked, is there a function to convert those fields to lowercase?

Comment: For lower case, there is `LOWER()` or `LCASE()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the database management system. In sql server would be:

```
UPDATE table SET field3 = field1 + '_' + field2
```

Whereas in Mysql it can be done with:

```
UPDATE table SET field3 = CONCAT_WS ('_', field1, field2)
```

Comment: In MySQL you could also do CONCAT(field1, '_', field2)

Comment: nice, that works, is there also a function to convert the fields to lowercase?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server:

```
UPDATE table SET field3 = field1 + '._.' + field2
```